# Does cold immersion after 6 hours post-workout enhance hypertrophy or strength?

Tags: muscle-gain, cold

It’s known that cold immersion within 6 hours after lifting will dampen gains by inhibiting muscular catabolism, and that more than 6 hours after working out does not have any adverse effect on gains.

But is it known whether this has a supportive effect on gains after >6 hours post-workout by enhancing anabolic activity?